# What does mapreduce framework write to split metainfo file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting the following error for a mapreduce job:

> Job initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Split metadata size
>   exceeded 10000000. Aborting job job_201511121020_1680 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.SplitMetaInfoReader.readSplitMetaInfo(SplitMetaInfoReader.java:48)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.createSplits(JobInProgress.java:828)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.initTasks(JobInProgress.java:730)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.initJob(JobTracker.java:3775)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.EagerTaskInitializationListener$InitJob.run(EagerTaskInitializationListener.java:90)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

The input path to this job is : /dir1/dir2/*/*/year/mon/day ... (7 days)

Here is what I gathered from research : this error is caused because the split meta info size exceeds the limit (set by mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize). I am assuming this meta data is written to a file and its the size of the file that has exceeded the limit.

I have few more questions :

1. Does the framework create one file or multiple files per job?
2. What are the contents of this file? Given that the input path is deep, however, when I write all files returned by the input path to a file, the size it only few MBytes.

Any help in better understanding this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default max size of split meta information is set to `10000000`

```
public static final long DEFAULT_SPLIT_METAINFO_MAXSIZE = 10000000L
```

You can override it by setting the configuration parameter: `mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize`, in mapred-site.xml.

Now coming to your questions:

1. One split file is created per job. The split file is stored in `.staging` folder for each job. The name of the split file is `job.split`.
2. The contents of this file are:

   ```
   1) Split file header: "META-SPL"

   2) Split file version: 1

   3) Number of splits

   4) Information about each split: 
      a) Locations of the split (a split can be present in 3 locations, if the replication factor is 3), 
      b) start offset
      c) length of the split.
   ```

You can find more information about `SplitMetaInfo` class here: [JobSplit.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/split/JobSplit.java)